# Read File line by line to variable and loop

Tags: c++, file-handling, file-io

I have a phone.txt like:

```
09236235965
09236238566
09238434444
09202645965
09236284567
09236235965
..and so on..
```

How can I process this data line by line in C++ and add it to a variable.

```
string phonenum;
```

I know I have to open the file, but after doing so, what is done to access the next line of the file?

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("phone.txt");
```

and also about the variable, the process will be looped, it will make the `phonenum` variable the current line its processing from the phone.txt.

Like if the first line is read `phonenum` is the first line, process everything and loop; now the `phonenum` is the 2nd line, process everything and loop until the end of the last line of the file.

Please help. I'm really new to C++. Thanks.

Comment: See [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the comments inline please. They will explain what is going on to assist you in learning how this works (hopefully):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // open the file if present, in read mode.
    std::ifstream fs("phone.txt");
    if (fs.is_open())
    {
        // variable used to extract strings one by one.
        std::string phonenum;

        // extract a string from the input, skipping whitespace
        //  including newlines, tabs, form-feeds, etc. when this
        //  no longer works (eof or bad file, take your pick) the
        //  expression will return false
        while (fs >> phonenum)
        {
            // use your phonenum string here.
            std::cout << phonenum << '\n';
        }

        // close the file.
        fs.close();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: hello, this is really great. anyways, is this correct? ifstream fs("D:\Read File Test\phone.txt");

Comment: Anyways one last thing. I tried the code, and it does the process 3 times even though I only have 2 lines on the text file. Why is that?

Comment: @user1553142 It should not. I've cut/paste your sample data to a text file and it performs as expected. one phonenum per entry. If you're using a debugger you might want to examine the content of phonenum and see what is present on either the first, or last, iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Simple. First, note that you want an `ifstream`, not an `ofstream`. When you're reading from a file, you're using it as input - hence the `i` in `ifstream`. You then want to loop, using `std::getline` to fetch a line from the file and process it:

```
std::ifstream file("phone.txt");
std::string phonenum;
while (std::getline(file, phonenum)) {
  // Process phonenum here
  std::cout << phonenum << std::endl; // Print the phone number out, for example
}
```

The reason why `std::getline` is the while loop condition is because it checks the status of the stream. If `std::getline` fails in anyway (at the end of your file, for example), the loop will end.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that :

```
 #include <fstream>
 using namespace std;

 ifstream input("phone.txt");

for( string line; getline( input, line ); )
{
  //code
}
```

Comment: For some reason there has been a lot of `using namespace std;` around here lately: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/using-namespace-std.html
  Also, why is `string line;` there twice? And you don't `#include <string>`.